# Magnetic Circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, energy

I'm trying to calculate the electromagnetic magnetic force on a plunger for a magnetic circuit.

The expression I have for the inductance is: $$ L = \frac{N^2 \mu \pi d^2}{4x} $$

and the expression I have for the energy stored in the magnetic field is:

$$w =\frac{N^2 \mu \pi d^2i^2}{8x} $$

The solution says that the electromagnetic force is: $$F =-\frac{N^2 \mu \pi d^2i^2}{8x^2} $$

I'm having difficulty relating the energy stored in the magnetic field to the electromagnetic force. My notes have the following formula:

$$ F = -\partial w/\partial x $$

When I did the partial derivative, I got:

$$F =\frac{N^2 \mu \pi d^2i^2}{8x^2} $$

I'm not sure how I'm getting the opposite sign since the x is the on denominator. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out. The book stated the following:

$$ F = -\frac{dW}{dx} =  \frac{i^2 \partial L}{ 2\partial x}$$

I then just subbed in my L value and got the right answer.